spring-integration-sftp failed to send channel
I have a spring-integrations-sftp configuration like below, basically it listens a remote directory and fetch the files and deletes afterwards.
   @Bean
   public SessionFactory<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> sessionFactory() {
        final DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(false);
        factory.setHost("a-host");
        factory.setPort(22);
        factory.setUser("username");
        factory.setTimeout(30000);
        factory.setPrivateKey("private-key-location");
        factory.setPrivateKeyPassphrase("passphrase");
        factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DatabasePollSkipStrategy testIncomingDatabasePollSkipStrategy(final DaoService daoService) {
        return new DatabasePollSkipStrategy(daoService, "samplePoller");
    }

    @Bean
    public PollSkipAdvice testIncomingPollSkipAdvice(final DatabasePollSkipStrategy testIncomingDatabasePollSkipStrategy) {
        return new PollSkipAdvice(testIncomingDatabasePollSkipStrategy);
    }

    @Bean
    public ChainFileListFilter<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> testIncomingChainFileListFilter(final ConcurrentMetadataStore metadataStore) {
        final ChainFileListFilter<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> chainFileListFilter = new ChainFileListFilter<>();
        chainFileListFilter.addFilter(new SftpRegexPatternFileListFilter("a-regex"));
        chainFileListFilter.addFilter(new SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(metadataStore, "a-prefix"));

        return chainFileListFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler testTaskScheduler() {
        final ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        taskScheduler.setAwaitTerminationSeconds(60);
        taskScheduler.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
        taskScheduler.setPoolSize(1);
        taskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("A-Task-Scheduler");

        return taskScheduler;
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow testIncomingIntegrationFlow(final ChainFileListFilter<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> testIncomingChainFileListFilter,
                                                       final SessionFactory<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> sessionFactory,
                                                       final ThreadPoolTaskScheduler testTaskScheduler,
                                                       final PollSkipAdvice testIncomingPollSkipAdvice) {
        final List<AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Option> optionList = new ArrayList<>();
        optionList.add(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Option.PRESERVE_TIMESTAMP);
        optionList.add(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Option.DELETE);

        final PollerSpec pollerSpec = getTestPollerSpec(testTaskScheduler, testIncomingPollSkipAdvice);

        return IntegrationFlows.from(() -> new GenericMessage<>("/a-remote-directory"), e -> e.poller(pollerSpec))
                .split()
                .log(message -> "1- LS.getPayload (Flow: test, Source: a-prefix) -> " + message.getPayload())
                .handle(Sftp.outboundGateway(sessionFactory,
                                AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Command.LS, "payload")
                        .options(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Option.RECURSIVE,
                                AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Option.NAME_ONLY)
                )
                .split()
                .log(message -> "2- MGET.getPayload (Flow: test, Source: a-prefix)-> " + message.getPayload())
                .handle(Sftp
                        .outboundGateway(sessionFactory, AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Command.MGET, "'"
                                + "/a-remote-directory" + "' + payload")
                        .options(optionList.toArray(new AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Option[0]))
                        .filter(testIncomingChainFileListFilter)
                        .localDirectoryExpression("'" + System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + File.separator +
                                "a-local-working-directory" + File.separator
                                + "a-prefix" + "' + #remoteDirectory")
                        .temporaryFileSuffix(FILE_SUFFIX)
                        .autoCreateLocalDirectory(true)
                        .fileExistsMode(REPLACE)
                )
                .handle(message -> fileService.handleMessage("a-prefix", "test", message))
                .get();
    }

    private PollerSpec getTestPollerSpec(final ThreadPoolTaskScheduler testTaskScheduler,
                                         final PollSkipAdvice testIncomingPollSkipAdvice) {
        return Pollers.cron("a-cron-expression")
                .maxMessagesPerPoll(1)
                .advice(testIncomingPollSkipAdvice)
                .taskExecutor(testTaskScheduler);
    }

However, we do receive often failed to send channel request. I tried to change the jsch library with the mwiede/jsch as well but same behaviour. Could you plaese suggest?
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to execute on session; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create SFTP Session
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:461)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.gateway.AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.doLs(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.java:607)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.gateway.AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.handleRequestMessage(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.java:584)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:136)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:55)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create SFTP Session
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:403)
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:60)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:447)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to connect
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.connect(SftpSession.java:301)
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:397)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: failed to send channel request
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Request.write(Request.java:65)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.RequestSftp.request(RequestSftp.java:47)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.start(ChannelSftp.java:237)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Channel.connect(Channel.java:152)
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.connect(SftpSession.java:296)
    ... 58 more

I also see the following in the jsch logs towards sFTP continuously but the exception doesn't happen always, let's say 1/10 attempts:
2024 07 16 10:54:34.867##UTC##INFO####an-application####com.jcraft.jsch##org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.JschLogger##log##Scheduler1##Authentications that can continue: gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
2024 07 16 10:54:34.867##UTC##INFO####an-application####com.jcraft.jsch##org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.JschLogger##log##Scheduler1##Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
2024 07 16 10:54:34.874##UTC##INFO####an-application####com.jcraft.jsch##org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.JschLogger##log##Scheduler1##Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
2024 07 16 10:54:34.874##UTC##INFO####an-application####com.jcraft.jsch##org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.JschLogger##log##Scheduler1##Next authentication method: publickey
2024 07 16 10:54:34.892##UTC##INFO####an-application####com.jcraft.jsch##org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.JschLogger##log##Scheduler1##Authentication succeeded (publickey).
2024 07 16 10:54:35.398##UTC##INFO####an-application####com.jcraft.jsch##org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.JschLogger##log##Scheduler1##Disconnecting from a-host port 22
2024 07 16 10:54:35.398##UTC##DEBUG####an-application####com.application.test##Scheduler1: incoming message payload -> []
2024 07 16 10:54:35.398##UTC##INFO####an-application####com.jcraft.jsch##org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.JschLogger##log##Connect thread a-host session##Caught an exception, leaving main loop due to Socket closed

By the way, it is not only above flow I can see the same exception for the following flow as well for example:
   public IntegrationFlow anOtherTestIncomingIntegrationFlow(final ChainFileListFilter<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> anOtherTestIncomingChainFileListFilter,
                                                              final ChainFileListFilter<File> anOtherTestIncomingLocalChainFileListFilter,
                                                              final ThreadPoolTaskScheduler anOtherTestIncomingTaskScheduler,
                                                              final SessionFactory<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> sessionFactory,
                                                              final PollSkipAdvice anOtherTestIncomingPollSkipAdvice) {
        final String remoteDirectory = "another-remote-directory";
        final String localDirectory = "another-local-directory";

        final PollerSpec pollerSpec = getPollerSpec(anOtherTestIncomingTaskScheduler, anOtherTestIncomingPollSkipAdvice);

        return IntegrationFlows.from(
                        Sftp.inboundAdapter(sessionFactory)
                                .preserveTimestamp(true)
                                .deleteRemoteFiles(true)
                                .remoteDirectory(remoteDirectory)
                                .localDirectory(Paths
                                        .get(localDirectory)
                                        .toAbsolutePath()
                                        .normalize()
                                        .toFile()
                                )
                                .autoCreateLocalDirectory(true)
                                .temporaryFileSuffix(FILE_SUFFIX)
                                .maxFetchSize(100)
                                .filter(anOtherTestIncomingChainFileListFilter)
                                .localFilter(anOtherTestIncomingLocalChainFileListFilter)
                                .autoCreateLocalDirectory(true),
                        e ->
                                e.id("anOtherTestBInboundAdapter")
                                        .autoStartup(true)
                                        .poller(pollerSpec))
                .handle(message -> fileService.handleMessage("a-source", "another-test", message))
                .get();
    }


That version of Spring Integration is out of support: https://spring.io/projects/spring-integration#support. Consider to upgrade to the latest one where SFTP implementation is based on Apache MINA: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/wiki/Spring-Integration-5.x-to-6.0-Migration-Guide#migrate-sftp-module-from-jsch-to-apache-mina

thank you for your comment Artem! Yes it is in my plan but since it is live, I need to resolve this before the upgrade. Because the upgrade requires infra work along with code update besides a full regression, this means that we need to live with this problem for a mid term.

Unfortunately I don't see how I can help you from Spring Integration perspective. Looks more like JCraft concern and connection with your SFTP server. Perhaps too many opened sockets, so your server close them forcefully.

If the flows look okay from your expert point of view, then maybe sFTP, OS, Network, or JCraft, but not spring-integration then. Thank you!

One caveat: see if that taskScheduler.setPoolSize(1); is really enough for. Usually there are much more tasks to be scheduled in parallel, so better to have more dedicated threads for that scheduler.

That .taskExecutor(testTaskScheduler) also feels wrong: why would one hand the task to another thread from scheduled one? Plus you already know that there is only one thread in that pool.

There is no way to override TaskScheduler for the AbstractPollingEndpoint from DSL API (yet). The TaskScheduler config can be overridden via bean with taskScheduler name.

just an update here Artem, after upgrading it to spring boot 3, the underlying issue is now more clear thanks to new apache ssh library. We do receive rarely timeouts from remote sftp but at the same time remote sftp often rejects our connection requests due to the high number of connections. I checked the open connections towards remote, it is around thousands. The #connection is increasing some time enourmously. After upgrade to 6.2 (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/9272), it seems now okay.

Sounds good! Feel free to add an answer to your question to let community know that there is a solution.
